# QML item's children list deep copy

Tags: qt, qml

I'd like to make a deep copy of an items children property. I've tried things along the lines:

```
Item {
  property variant itemsCopy

  Component.onCompleted: {
    var tmp = otherItem.children
    itemsCopy = tmp
  }
}
```

But when otherItem.children is changed (sorted due to different Z values), `itemsCopy` is also changed. Is there a workaround to break the binding or a way to prevent children from being sorted? I've tried Array s, list, nothing works. Changing members of tmp is ignored.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could take a copy yourself:

```
import QtQuick 1.0

Item {
  property variant itemsCopy

  Component.onCompleted: {
    var tmp = otherItem.children
    var copy = []
    for (var i = 0; i < tmp.length; ++i)
        copy[i] = tmp[i]
    itemsCopy = copy;
  }
}
```

In QtQuick 2.0 it is a little easier as you can use `property var`:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Item {
  property var itemsCopy: []

  Component.onCompleted: {
    var tmp = otherItem.children
    for (var i = 0; i < tmp.length; ++i) 
        itemsCopy[i] = tmp[i]
  }
}
```

Comment: Appears to work, even though the attached properties of the items become inaccessible.

Answer (score 6):

In the example provided by MartinJ all objects will be copied by reference. Here is a classic deep copy function from "Object-Oriented JavaScript" book:

```
function deepCopy(p, c) {
    var c = c || {};
    for (var i in p) {
        if (typeof p[i] === 'object') {
            c[i] = (p[i].constructor === Array) ? [] : {};
            deepCopy(p[i], c[i]);
        } else {
            c[i] = p[i];
        }
    }
    return c;
}
```